# Unable to update the recyclerview list after adding posting a chat message in android using Java

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I need add the message in my recyclerview in android. But it failed to add in the list after adding the notifyDataSetChaged().

Here is my code

Used adapter and fragment.

Adapter will show the receiver and sender messsage in left and right as per the user id. Bind holder id used for showing the list of own user and other user messages in the left and right as same as wapp.

Chat Fragment:

```
   public void onviewCreated() {
    
     mSendMsg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String msgContent = mSendMsgInputBox.getText().toString();
    
                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(msgContent))
                {
                    execute(new PostMessageRequest( msgContent,getmId()), mPostMessageListener);
                    int i1 = msharedprefs.getInt(msgContent, 0);
                    i1 += 1;
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = msharedprefs.edit();
                    editor.putInt(msgContent, i1);
                    editor.commit();
                    int newMsgPosition = messagesList.size();
                    System.out.println("newMsgPosition ==" + newMsgPosition);
    
                    // Notify recycler view insert one new data.
                    mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(newMsgPosition);
                    // Scroll RecyclerView to the last message.
                    //mChatMessageRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
    
                 
                    mSendMsgInputBox.setText("");
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    
                }
            }
        });
    
    My Adapter:


       private static final int VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT = 1;
        private static final int VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED = 2;
        private List<MyMessageModel> msgDtoList; 
        MyMessageModel msgDto = this.msgDtoList.get(position);
         

         @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        MyMessageModel message = (MyMessageModel) msgDtoList.get(position);

        if (message.getId().equals(Profile.getId())) {
            // If the current user is the sender of the message
            return VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT;
        } else {
            // If some other user sent the message
            return VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED;
        }
    }

 @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;

        if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.sender_message_layout, parent, false);
            return new SenderMessageHolder(view);

        } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.receiver_message_layout, parent, false);
            return new ReceiverMessageHolder(view);
        }
    return null;
    }
             public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
                LastMessageContent message = (LastMessageContent) msgDtoList.get(position);
            
                switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
                    case VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT:
                        populateSentViewHolder(holder, position);   break;
                    case VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED:
                        populateReceivedViewHolder(holder, position);
            
                }

 @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    private void populateSentViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MyMessageModal msgDto = this.msgDtoList.get(position);
        ((SenderMessageHolder) holder).rightMsgTextView.setText(msgDto.getmMSg());
}

 @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    private void populateReceivedViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MyMessageModal msgDto = this.msgDtoList.get(position);
        ((ReceiverMessageHolder) holder).leftMsgTextView.setText(msgDto.getmMSg());
}
```

Comment: Try adding `mChatMessageRecyclerView.requestLayout();` afert `.notifyItemInserted` , without `.notifyDataSetChanged`

Comment: Many pieces of code are missing, so it's difficult......However you're notifying using "notifyItemInserted(newMsgPosition)" but scrolling to position=0 and if "newMsgPosition" is enough high then this new item goes outside first ListView page and the View is not updated until scroll to "scrollToPosition(newMsgPosition)". But this is just a supposition because is not clear how you add and get Items....

Comment: I will post a message in the chat when the user hit on the send message icon in the chat screen. It will make a post call i.e the execute will hit a post message. After this I need to update that message in my recyclerview list. Here the post call get succeeded, but it failed to show the added item in the recyclerview list. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @emandt As per you my new position is always 0 only. Can you let me know how the position get update?

Comment: I have added the position as  int newMsgPosition = mAdapter.getItemCount() + 1; Now I can able to receive the position, but still it failed to update in the recyclerview list.

Comment: I wrote you that there are a lot of piece of code missing....especially what is "msgDtoList" (and why it is used in onBindViewHolder()) and what "populateSentViewHolder(..)" and "populateReceivedViewHolder(..)" do, so I cannot help you so much....

Comment: I have used the msgList from my model. Here the onBindView holder will show the chat in left and right side, same as the chat in wapp. @emandt updated.

Comment: I think the way you choose Right/Left is wrong. RecycleView creates ONCE the right amount of Views to be displayed in a single "page" and then reuse them during scrolling....but if an Item/View is Inflated as "Right" it cannot be used as "Left" because "onCreateViewHolder()" is not called more for it. Choosing R/L should be done in "onBindViewHolder()" using a parameter without inflating anything but just hide/show Left or Right version of it. However "msgDtoList" seems not been updated so I don't understand how Adapter could display something if "msgDtoList" seems always in an empty state.

Comment: But the message for r/l will be shown most of the example method is in this way. I can able to see the left and right side messages using the above method. The recyclerview will shows the list once. I have checked if the user id and the sender id are same view needs to shows the left layout(receiver_message_layout). Otherwise right in a separate xml.(sender_message_layout)

Comment: Are you saying I need to use only one xml for the both and needs to show the view according to the sender and receiver?

Comment: Are you ever adding the message to `messageDtoList`? It looks like you're calling `notifyDatasetChanged` without ever changing the data?

Comment: Well you've got a list in the adapter that you filled with items, without adding the new items you'll never get any change? Both approaches work with your R/L messages, realistically I don't think it'll make much difference.

Comment: Okay thanks. Can I make the grouping of messages with the date here same as wapp?

Comment: By wapp do you mean WhatsApp? If so then are you referring to the date labels they put above each day's messages?

Comment: Yes, exactly referring the Whatsapp.

Comment: @HenryTwist My timestamp will be like below. How can I compare for lot of messages in this time format?.2021-03-24'T'07:08:55'Z'

Comment: Explaining it seems beyond the scope of this question, you can research how to sort a list, there's plenty of documentation out there!

Comment: I think it is grouping of essages and shown for a particular day

Comment: @HenryTwist I have added the list value. But after this the getViewType not returns my id and shows the error as here, and shows null object reference. But the getItemCount size getincreased after sending the message 
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        MyMessageModel message = (MyMessageModel) msgDtoList.get(position);
        System.out.println("message == " + message());